# vi: how can I jump to end of file with a new line appended?

Tags: vi

Here's an answer I want about 5 times a day.

In vi, the command to go to the end of the file is `G`.

But that always leaves me at the start of the last line of the file, if files don't have a blank line at the end.

How can I jump to the end of the file and append a new blank line, so that I can just start typing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What about <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, successively?  ;-)

Comment: @Richard Also check out the capital 'O' command if you aren't familiar with that one. It creates a new line above the current one and puts you in insert mode.

Comment: @binfalse : Many times while coding we want to start a new code block, so after the end of file, we need to skip a line and then enter `insert` mode, if I use `G2o`, then I am moved to the next line to the `EOF` and into `insert` mode and when I **move back to normal mode another line is created, to which I'm instantly shifted**, how to go to insert mode after 2/n lines ?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative with command line:

```
:$put _
```

If you want to understand that, you can also read [this answer on registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line/3997110#3997110)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a macro and place it in your .vimrc file.

```
map , GA<enter>
```

This will map the comma key.  When pressed, vi will go to the end of the file, go to the end of that line and create a new blank line.  This will also leave you in insert / edit mode.

Comment: `A<enter>` ? `o` as suggested by @binfalse, is the right way!